# Volttron Crate Historian Error: Invalid data not saved

Tags: python, database, crate, volttron, historian

Hope you are doing great.

The CrateHistorian is not working. I have installed it with the following configurations:

```
{
    "connection": {
        "type": "crate",
        # Optional table prefix defaults to historian
        "schema": "monday_schema",
        "params": {
            "host": "localhost:4200"
        }
    }
}
```

Watching crate admin UI on `localhost:4200`, I get two tables created with names **data** and **topics**.

The topics are stored in the topics tables but the data table doesn't add anything.

Tried running tail **volttron.log** to see what might be the issue and got this result for crate agent:

2021-02-08 15:02:32,748 (cratedbagent-3.3 8267) **main** DEBUG: Invalid data not saved ('2021-02-08T09:47:40.340678+00:00', 'my_campus/my_building/room2/Setpoint.3', 'scrape', 63.0, {'units': 'degreesFahrenheit', 'type': 'integer', 'tz': 'UTC'})

And this is done for all the data points I am trying to save.

*What might be the issue in configurations?*

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting this data from?  The format for historian is based upon https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/agent-framework/historian-agents/historian-topic-syntax.html.

Note the syntax differences between what is pasted up above and the following:

```
# Message Format:

# WITH METADATA
# Messages contains a two element list.  The first element contains a
# dictionary of all points under a specific parent.  While the second
# element contains a dictionary of meta data for each of the specified
# points.  For example devices/pnnl/building/OutsideAirTemperature and
# devices/pnnl/building/MixedAirTemperature ALL message would be created as:
[
    {"OutsideAirTemperature ": 52.5, "MixedAirTemperature ": 58.5},
    {
       "OutsideAirTemperature ": {'units': 'F', 'tz': 'UTC', 'type': 'float'},
       "MixedAirTemperature ": {'units': 'F', 'tz': 'UTC', 'type': 'float'}
    }
]
```

Is this the platform driver (former master driver) or from a different agent publishing to the topic?

Comment: Yes, it's a platform driver which is using a BACnet Proxy agent for reading data from BACnet IP devices.